# Access YQL from ASP.NET & MVC

Tags: asp.net, yql

Is there a recommended methodology / technique for accessing YQL from ASP.NET (&MVC). I'm Thinking something like LINQ ? I'd like to be able to treat it like a local SQL DB as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing I don't know if it's possible (now) to use LINQ, but what about using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) for results? Don't know about performance, but [you could use LINQ to JSON](http://www.joshnock.com/post/YQL-Yahoo-Query-Language-and-JsonNET.aspx).